# Como hacer que seleccione en el combo un valor por defecto en Angular JS 1.5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estoy haciendo un Edit desde un Modal pero no logro que me muestre los datos que traer desde el controllador, solo me aparece el campo vacio, nota: si funcionan bien los selects.

Aqui mi HTML

```
<div class = "row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
<label>CLase Lente</label>
<select ng-options="clase as clase.nombre for clase in clases track by clase.codigo"
    ng-model="codigo_clase_lente"
    class="form-control">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Color Lente</label>
<select ng-options="color as color.nombre for color in colores track by color.codigo" 
        ng-model="codigo_color_lente"
        class="form-control">
 </select>
</div>
</div>
```

aqui mi codigo.

```
   cargarClases = function(){
   $http.get('/listClases').success(function(response){
        console.log('Lista Clases de Lentes cargadas');
        console.log(response);
        $scope.clases = response;
        $scope.codigo_clase_lente = response.codigo
    })
}

cargarColores = function(){
   $http.get('/listColores').success(function(response){
        console.log('Lista Colores de Lentes cargadas');
        console.log(response);
        $scope.colores = response;
        $scope.codigo_color_lente = response.codigo
    })
}
```

Comment: El contenido de la respuesta está en la entrada `data`. Es decir, para guardar las clases y colores, deberías hacer uso de `response.data`.

Comment: @guzgarcia la data si la guarda, pero lo que trato de hacer esque al llamar la "orden" se muestre el valor que trae desde la BD por que es un edit.

Comment: Deberías entonces decir, *"que seleccione en el combo un valor por defecto"*. Según veo ya tienes establecido el `ng-model` por lo que, en teoría, si el valor de éste modelo es igual al valor de algún objeto en el select, éste debería estar seleccionado. ¿Te aseguraste que `codigo_clase_lente` y `codigo_color_lente` tengan los valores esperados?

Comment: Corrección hecha en el titulo, tengo un objeto en el ng-model y si le asigno valores pero no pasa nada, pero tiene que ser un objeto o se puede poner solo el id? por ejemplo orden.codigo_color.

Comment: No. El `ng-model` yo siempre lo he usado, en el caso de selects, como un objeto; así lo indica la [documentación](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects). ¿Has usado valores planos?

Comment: La verdad que no, tengo una semana de estar experimentando con Angular

Answer (score 0):

Si los selects funcionan perfectamente, entonces puedes utilizar esto

```
cargarClases = function(){
   $http.get('/listClases').success(function(response){
        console.log('Lista Clases de Lentes cargadas');
        console.log(response);
        $scope.clases = response;
        $scope.codigo_clase_lente = response[0];
    })
}

cargarColores = function(){
   $http.get('/listColores').success(function(response){
        console.log('Lista Colores de Lentes cargadas');
        console.log(response);
        $scope.colores = response;
        $scope.codigo_color_lente = response[0];
    })
}
```

Dado que lo que estas recibiendo del API es un arreglo. Puedes agregar una validación antes para validar que la respuesta tenga elementos.